# Unable to connect to the database - Mongoose nestJS

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

Currently I Attempt to connect to a database mongodb. But I get it error:

```
[MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... +30015ms
```

I use connection through openshift, something like that:

```
oc port-forward mongors-0 27019:27017
```

In the code configuration in nestJs I have follow:

```
    @Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forRoot( serviceConfig.mongoUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: false }),
    CommonModule, AccountingModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The problems is when I use this configuration option: useUnifiedTopology: true, when I use the value false the connection is correct.

The serviceConfig.mongoUrl value is:

```
mongodb://localhost:27019/PAGOS
```

If someone Can help me, I apreciate that.

Thanks
Regards

Comment: After it finises all the retries, what's the error? There's not really much to go on here.

Comment: Hello @JayMcDoniel, After it finises all the retries the app doesn't run and throw this error: 
`MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`

Answer (score 4):

Try change `localhost` => `127.0.0.1`

I had same problem, this works fine

Comment: But why does this happen?